# Catalog 'hive' does not support table property 'textfile_field_separator'

Tags: hive, presto

I tried to create hive table by presto sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp.test_q WITH (
  format = 'TEXTFILE',
  textfile_field_separator = ','
),
```

but got

```
com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException: Catalog 'hive' does not support table property 'textfile_field_separator'
```

Our presto is about 0.26X version.
how to set the delimiter?

Thanks

Comment: there is no such property textfile_field_separator in presto. Have you tried creating this table directly in catalog and then query it? What do you see if don't mention textfile_field_separator in presto. Update your question with issue encountered and sample rows

Answer (score 0):

You try `format = 'PARQUET'`.

It looks like mismatching between the format and the property under format.